# Boundary integral method to solve Poisson equation

Tags: numerical-methods, laplace-transform, finite-differences, boundary-value-problem, poisson-geometry

Suggest how to solve Poisson equation
\begin{equation}
   σ  ∇^2 V = - I δ(x-x_s) δ(y-y_s) δ(z-z_s) \nonumber
\end{equation}
by using the boundary integration method to calculate the potential $V(r,z)$ with the help of changing the Poisson equation into cylindrical polar co ordinates?
Where $V$ is electric Potential (scalar)[volts]. Solution depends only on $r$ and $σ$ is constant. $r$ is  horizontal coordinate(direction) $0\leq r \leq \infty $ and $z$ is vertical co ordinate(direction) $-\infty\leq r \leq \infty $. What boundary conditions are appropriate?

=>
Poisson equation
\begin{equation}
   σ  ∇^2 V = - I δ(x-x_s) δ(y-y_s) δ(z-z_s) \nonumber
\end{equation}
can be written as 
\begin{equation}
   σ  ∇^2 V = - I δ(X-X_0)  \nonumber
\end{equation}

where $I$ is current or source intensity and we take $I$ as $1$.

$δ(x-x_s) δ(y-y_s) δ(z-z_s)$ is source term.

$ δ$ is Dirac delta function.

The Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates is:

\begin{equation}
- ∇^2 V=  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}[ r \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}] + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial z^2}
\end{equation}
$\theta$ is not relevant, so it goes to zero.

\begin{equation}
- ∇^2 V=  \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}[ r \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}] +\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial z^2}
\end{equation}
cylindrical polar co ordinates is
\begin{equation}
 \int ^{r= ∞}_ {r=0} \int^ {z=∞} _{ z= - ∞} {δ(r)  δ(z-z_s)} dz dr.
\end{equation}
where $r_s$ is $0$.

( green function) $G_{3D}= \frac{- 1}{4πσ r} = \frac{∂G}{∂r} + \frac{1}{r} ≈ 0$  on boundary $\Gamma_\infty$

where $r$ is $|X-X_0|$.  $\sigma$ is constant with respect to one of the variables $r$ or $z$ but solution depend upon $r$ only.

No current flux on a surface with normal $n$:  $ σ \frac{∂V}{∂n} =0$ [ Neumann boundary condition ]

now my question is how do I tackle the problem by using the boundary integral method with the help above equations.

can anyone please help me.

Comment: The question IMHO is not formulated correctly. Please try to improve some. I have the impression that you are messing up "cylindrical" and "spherical" in the first place. Why not locate the source simply at the origin? And what is "v" in comparison with "V"? To mention a few things ..